# Prediction distribution of Gaussian process in weight-view space

Tags: normal-distribution, machine-learning, regression

From (2.9) in [Chapter 2](https://gaussianprocess.org/gpml/chapters/RW2.pdf) of the book by Rasmussen, prediction using Gaussian processes in the weight-space view is

> $$\begin{aligned}p\left(f_{*} | \mathbf{x}_{*}, X, \mathbf{y}\right) &= \int p\left(f_{*} | \mathbf{x}_{*}, \mathbf{w}\right) p(\mathbf{w} | X, \mathbf{y}) d \mathbf{w} \\ 
> &= \mathcal{N}\big(\frac{1}{\sigma_n^2}\mathbf{x_*^T}A^{-1}X\mathbf{y}, \mathbf{x_*^T}A^{-1}\mathbf{x_*}\big)
> \end{aligned}$$

where $A = \frac{1}{\sigma_n^2}XX^T + \Sigma_p^{-1}$, with $\Sigma_p$ being the covariance matrix of prior on $\mathbf{w}$.

I do not understand the first term of the integrand.

*Assuming* (this might be wrong) $p(f_*|\mathbf{x_*, w})=\mathcal{N}(\mathbf{w^Tx^*},\sigma_f^2)$, the integral yields
$$\mathcal{N}\big(\frac{1}{\sigma_n^2}\mathbf{x_*^T}A^{-1}X\mathbf{y}, \sigma_f^2 + \mathbf{x_*^T}A^{-1}\mathbf{x_*}\big)$$

This matches the expression given in the book if $\sigma_f=0$. Does this mean $p(f_*|\mathbf{x_*, w})$ is a Dirac Delta distribution, centered at $\mathbf{w^Tx^*}$?

---

Additionally, slide 30 [here](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/%7Ehinton/csc2515/notes/gp_slides_fall08.pdf) mentions

> $$P(f_*|\mathbf{y},X) = \int d\theta P(f_*|\mathbf{y},X,\theta) P(\theta|\mathbf{y},X)$$
> The first term in the integrand is tractable.

What does the last statement mean?

---

I had earlier asked this on CrossValidated, but did not receive any response. Deleted from there.
Questions similar to this on CV: [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=Predictive+distribution+of+Gaussian+processes). But they do not answer my question.

Comment: I am stuggling the same equation as well. According to one of the comments [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/410110/predictive-distribution-in-gaussian-process-derivation?noredirect=1&lq=1), it is a delta function. But even if I treat it as delta function, I still cannot solve the problem (see my question [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/624695/predictive-distribution-in-gaussian-process-for-machine-learning).